# Populte WYSIWYG editor after react native fetch

Tags: react-native

I am trying to incorporate this [WYSIWYG package](https://github.com/wxik/react-native-rich-editor) into my react native project (`0.64.3`). I built my project with a managed workflow via Expo (`~44.0.0`).

The problem I am noticing is that the editor will sometimes render with the text from my database and sometimes render without it.

Here is a snippet of the function that retrieves the information from firebase.

```
const [note, setNote] = useState("");
const getNote = () => {
    const myDoc = doc(db,"/users/" + user.uid + "/Destinations/Trip-" + trip.tripID + '/itinerary/' + date);
    getDoc(myDoc)
    .then(data => { 
        setNote(data.data()[date]);
    }).catch();
  }
```

The above code and the editor component are nested within a large function

```
export default function ItineraryScreen({route}) {

// functions 

return (
    <RichEditor
        onChange={newText => {
            setNote(newText)
        }}
        scrollEnabled={false}
        ref={text}
        initialFocus={false}
        placeholder={'What are you planning to do this day?'}
        initialContentHTML={note}
    />
)
}
```

Here is what it should look like with the text rendered (screenshot of simulator):

[image]

But this is what I get most of the time (screenshot from physical device):

[image]

My assumption is that there is a very slight delay between when the data for the text editor is actually available vs. when the editor is being rendered. I believe my simulator renders correctly because it is able to process the getNote() function faster.

what I have tried is using a `setTimeOut` function to the `display` of the parent `View` but it does not address the issue.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved the issue. I needed to parse the response better before assigning a value to `note` and only show the editor and toolbar once a value was established.

Before firebase gets queried, I assigned a `null` value to `note`

```
const [note, setNote] = useState(null);
```

Below, I will always assign value to `note` regardless of the outcome.

```
if(data.data() !== undefined){
    setNote(data.data()[date]);
} else {
    setNote("");
}
```

The last step was to only show the editor once `note` no longer had a null value.

```
{
   note !== null &&
      <RichToolbar
         style={{backgroundColor:"white", width:"114%", flex:1, position:"absolute", left:0, zIndex:4, bottom: (toolbarVisible) ? keyboardHeight * 1.11 : 0 , marginBottom:-40, display: toolbarVisible ? "flex" : "none"}}
         editor={text}
         actions={[ actions.undo, actions.setBold, actions.setItalic, actions.setUnderline,actions.insertLink, actions.insertBulletsList, actions.insertOrderedList, actions.keyboard ]}
         iconMap={{ [actions.heading1]: ({tintColor}) => (<Text style={[{color: tintColor}]}>H1</Text>), }}
                  />
          
      <RichEditor
         disabled={disableEditor}
         initialFocus={false}
         onChange={ descriptionText => { setNote(descriptionText) }}
         scrollEnabled={true}
         ref={text}
         placeholder={'What are you planning to do?'}
         initialContentHTML={note}
      />
}
```

It is working properly.